# Crash app for download image?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, universal-image-loader

I use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library in my project and this is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPageAdapter adapter;
private String[] images={
        "http://s1.picofile.com/file/8287195734/p3.png",
        "http://s1.picofile.com/file/8287195734/p3.png",
        "http://s1.picofile.com/file/8287195734/p3.png"
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageLoaderConfiguration confing = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(confing);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    adapter = new ViewPageAdapter(MainActivity.this,images,ImageLoader.getInstance());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

I am watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVn2yQACH_g) in YouTube
When I lunch app exit ,I write permission in manifest.
and in `logcat` say mistake in Twenty-second line in `MainActivity`,this is a Twenty-second line in `MainActivity`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and this is my activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="comicc.idea.com.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.view.viewpager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post the execption from logcat

Comment: where is the error ?

Comment: I think the error is inside your activity_main xml please upload activity_main.xml or upload error log cat.